# Ant build configuration resources folder

Tags: android, ant

I am trying to use ant to do an android built. Using one code base I am trying to deploy two different applications that use different resources. At the moment the solution below is working but it seems a bit of a hassle when working with it because it will copy and paste entire structure to the "res" folder every time you want to do the build, not knowing which build resources are in the "res" folder, plus excluding layout folder as a common in "res".

I would like to know if there is a way in ant to change the name of the folder from "res" to something else during build time. That way GNA project will be the root in "res" folder and BSF will have its folder and no need to copy paste.

I would appreciate any help with this! Thank you.

```
<target name="gna" description="GNA Application Deployment" depends="clean">    
    <copy todir="${basedir}/res" overwrite="true" force="true" includeEmptyDirs="true" >
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/res-gna" >
            <exclude name="**/layout" />   
        </fileset>
    </copy>

</target>

<target name="bsf" depends="clean" description="BSF Application Deployment" depends="clean">
    <copy todir="${basedir}/res" overwrite="true" force="true" includeEmptyDirs="true" >
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/res-bsf" >
            <exclude name="**/layout/**" />   
        </fileset>
    </copy>

</target>
```

Comment: android resources are used to auto-generate `R.java`.  I am not sure what you are trying to do here.

Comment: lets say i am simply trying to change the name of the folder where resources are kept from "res" to "res-nga" so ant can use that folder during build to compile the project